# Information duplication vs separation of concerns

Tags: javascript, jquery, theory

I'm working on a HTML table generated by jQuery.  My first instinct is to pair the table with a regular two-dimensional array where I can do easily the manipulations I want.

At first, it seemed like a great idea, but I'm realizing that it involves some nasty information duplication. 
On the other hand, it could improve the separation between the logic and the view.

Does separation of concerns contradict the "don't repeat yourself" principle?  If so, what principle should be preferred? If not, what model of design can overcome the apparent paradox?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to read/manipulate the data *directly* from the table? If not, then transforming the data into array form should not be an issue; you are merely applying data *transformation*.
However, if you CAN read/manipulate the data directly from the table, then do so.

Comment: This is a comment only.  Please place it as such on the question when you are able.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what "directly" means, but I guess I would be able to manage it.  However I'm more interested about the theoretical aspect of the problem, e.g. what kind of edge cases are to be expected or what is the general accepted best practices.